# How does Windows schedule a thread when the thread has no process?

Tags: windows, rootkits, kernel

I have heard that some rootkits try to hide themselves by destroying the process object (`nt!_EPROCESS` ?) but keeping the thread alive (`nt!_ETHREAD` ?) . That way they are not visible in tools like Task Manager or Process Explorer, which display processes.

I know that the total priority of a thread is calculated from two parts:

1. the process priority, e.g. defined via [CreateProcess() (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), parameter `dwCreationFlags` which takes a [Priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683211(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. the thread priority, e.g. set via [SetThreadPriority() (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277(v=vs.85).aspx)

Now, if the process object containing the priority information was destroyed by the rootkit, wouldn't the Windows kernel fail when trying to calculate the total priority of that hidden rootkit thread?

Comment: The rootkit might have installed a hook in SetThreadPriority() and CreateProcess() and/or any other windows api function to modify return parameters. Depending on the type of rootkit there is no way to tell how exactly it's hiding.

Comment: @Skynet: IMHO, the Windows kernel will not use those methods. It will use the properties of the _EPROCESS and _ETHREAD structures which are available in kernel space. I added those names to the question

Comment: Yes, that's most likely true. (Would be very insecure to rely on functions that can be modified from user mode). What i wanted to say is that you need to specify the access level of the rootkit (user, kernel or even firmware). Because a kernel rootkit could definitely modify such critical structures.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, all threads of a process share same code and data segments. At any moment, a *program* can ask for its ThreadId and ProcessId. And a process only actually ends when all of its threads do.

But a malware can hide its activity behind a `rundll32` process. This is just a system process that is used for example when services are implemented only through a DLL and not through an executable. As you find such processes commonly in task manager list, it is hard to guess where a malicious activity is hidden behind.